# yum equivalent of rpm --nofiledigest/--nomd5

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, yum, rpm

I have a package that I would like to install. However, I get the following error when doing so

```
 # yum install package.rpm
 ...
 Transaction test succeeded
 Running transaction
 Installing : package.i686                                                                                                         
 1/1 
 Error unpacking rpm package package.i686
 error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/use;642dc5ca: cpio: Digest mismatch
 Verifying  : package.i686                                                                                                         
 1/1
```

The only way I have found to install this package is via:

```
 # rpm -ivh --nofiledigest package.i686
```

Is there an equivalent option for yum for --nofiledigest/--nomd5?

Comment: What would installing a binary file that is definitely broken do for you? It won't work. There seems to be some header corruption going on in the data part of that rpm. So, you need a non-brokrn RPM, no way around that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller how are you able to tell that there is header corruption? What is meant here by "header corruption"? Just trying to learn...

Comment: The error lists a file name that seems to be corrupt; that the file then falls integrity checking seems logical

Answer (score 0):

Yum/DNF have no such options. Even for RPM it looks misplaced. The package must not be installed if it fails hashsum checking - it can actually be a security/integrity risk.